# CartThrob - Send customer IP to Authorize.net

Tags: cartthrob

Does anyone know how to send a customers IP address to authorize.net when an order is placed in CartThrob. The IP is currently saved in the orders channel but I don't know to send it to authorize.net.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to send the IP address to authorize.net by adding:

```
"x_customer_ip"                 => $this->order('ip_address')
```

to the process_payment function in Carthrob_authorize_net.php.